# How much heat energy is required to bring 1 liter of water to the critical point?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, evaporation, phase-diagram

This is not a homework question.

The [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)) of water is 374 C and 22.06 MPa. At the critical point the latent heat of vaporization is 0 - why?

Assume the water starts at 100 C.

If you add the heat required to raise the temperature of water by 274 degrees - using 4200 J / kg, it doesn't add up to the heat required to vaporize water. Each degree of temperature requires 4200 J/kg so 374 - 100 = 274 * 4200 = 1,150,800 Joules. This is roughly half the latent heat of vaporization required to vaporize a kilogram of water - 2260 kJ/kg.

Even if I use values from an Isobaric specific heat chart which shows the specific heat increasing substantially at higher temperatures, it still doesn't add up. There's still ~608,000 joules short.

I've read in several studies that higher temperatures decrease the strength of hydrogen bonds. Inversely, low pressures also decrease the strength of hydrogen bonds. Could this decreased strength in Van Der Waals forces be the reason less heat is required to render the heat of vaporization zero at the critical point?

Comment: It's not a homework question. Please re-open.

Comment: Do I have to repost it?

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is going on look at the $P-H$ graph of steam. The heat of vaporization is the length of the tie line, that's the line that connects the saturated vapor to the saturated liquid at constant pressure. At 100°C this is the distance $AC$ in the graph. Tie lines get shorter as we move up and at the critical point the tie line collapses into a point. The length of the critical tie line is 0, and that's equal to the heat of vaporization at the critical point.

When you calculate the heat to go from state A (saturated liquid at 100°C) to the critical point you are actually calculating the length AB, assuming that the path is ABD. Other paths are possible and will generally require different amounts of heat. This heat has nothing to do with the heat of vaporization at the critical point.

[image: PH chart of steam]

I took the $PH$ chart from [here](http://ouopentextbooks.org/thermodynamics/files/2015/07/ph_water.gif).