# Why is the latent heat of vaporization 0 at the critical point?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, evaporation, phase-diagram

This is not a homework question.

The critical point of water is $\mathrm{374 \ C}$ and $\mathrm{22.06 \ MPa}$. At the critical point the latent heat of vaporization is $0$ - why?

Assume the water starts at $\mathrm{100 \ C}$.

If you add the heat required to raise the temperature of water by $\mathrm{274 \ degrees}$ - using $\mathrm{4200 \ J / kg}$, it doesn't add up to the heat required to vaporize water. Each degree of temperature requires $\mathrm{4200 \ J/kg}$ so $374 - 100 = 274 × 4200 = 1$, $150$ , $\mathrm{800 \ Joules}$. This is roughly half the latent heat of vaporization required to vaporize a kilogram of water - $\mathrm{2260 \ kJ/kg}$.

Even if I use values from an Isobaric specific heat chart which shows the specific heat increasing substantially at higher temperatures, it still doesn't add up. There's still $\mathrm{~608,000 \ joules}$ short.

I've read in several studies that higher temperatures decrease the strength of hydrogen bonds. Inversely, low pressures also decrease the strength of hydrogen bonds. Could this decreased strength in Van Der Waals forces be the reason less heat is required to render the heat of vaporization zero at the critical point?

Comment: At the critical point the liquid and the gas phases are *identical* states of matter, so no external heat is required to turn one into the other.

Comment: Do you want to take a stab at the second part of the question? You are correct in your answer, but I want to understand why that is the case if there isn't enough heat to vaporize the water.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681567/2451

Comment: Both the latent heat and the specific heat are temperature dependent, so the 4,200 J/Kg is not valid at the higher temperatures.

Comment: Mike Stone - So, the strength of hydrogen bonds decrease as temperature increases? Do you know where I can find that documented? Also, if possible, where can I find documentation or studies that show this and / or that hydrogen bonds weaken with decreased pressure.

Comment: I think you are also forgetting that in the Latent heat calculation you are forgetting that a substantial part of the latent heat goes into the work$P\Delta V $  needed to expand the  water vapour against atmospheric pressure. In your critical point route     you are heating the water in a closed container at fixed volume so that that work does not have to be done.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "against atmospheric" since it is under a much higher pressure than atm. Also, if much of the latent heat goes into the work required to push against the pressure, wouldn't that require more heat overall? The specific heat of the water does increase as pressure increases, but even so, the total amount of heat added doesn't add up to the amount of heat that should be required to vaporize the water - especially if you add all heat needed to raise the temp of water to 374 + latent heat required to vaporize. Yet at the critical point latent heat is 0.

Comment: My apologies, I see what you pointed out as the difference between applying latent heat at atmospheric compared to latent heating under pressure. A quick stab at the math: increasing temp of 1 liter of water +274 C = 1,652 kJ (based on isobaric specific heat chart). Latent heat of vaporization should be 2,257 kJ / kg. That's a total of 3,909 kJ. However, to reach the critical point, only the heat to raise the temp to 374 C is accounted for, which is 1,652 kJ / kg. That's only 42% of the heat required. This accounts for the increased specific heat under pressure.

Comment: I'll calculate the work of the pressure to see how much that adds.